# Nginx, fastcgi PHP Windows, No input file specified

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Running php-cgi on port 9000

Netstat gives me

`TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         DESKTOP-xxxxxxx:0      LISTENING
 [php-cgi.exe]`

nginx.conf

http://pastebin.com/wkfz8wxw

Every php file gives me this `No input file specified.` error...

Changed `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to `SCRIPT_NAME` and no succes..

I am on Windows 10 Home x64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set a document root with the `root` directive, either within your `location ~ \.php$` block or inherited from the outer `server` block.

The solution may be to move the `root c:/Users/Youri/PhpstormProjects;` line out of your `location /` block into a position above it.

Usually `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` is the correct method to specify the full path to the script, whereas `SCRIPT_NAME` is usually just the last element.

Like this:

```
server {
    ...

    root   c:/Users/Youri/PhpstormProjects;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if i change the ``root`` directive out of the ``server`` block i wont make a dirrerence...

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Should i use the non threat safe or threat safe php version?

Comment: @Yooouuri I am not familiar with Windows or php-cgi.

Comment: No problem. I moved the ``root`` and ``ìndex`` directive from the ``location /`` to the ``server`` block and everything works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Set root directive with absolute path in windows PC. 
Check for the case or any typing mistake in the path.
Reload the nginx process.

Comment: +1 I searched high and low, and it turns out the lack of an absolute path was the problem. Use forward slashes!

Answer (score 1):

May be the `root` path problem. I used the backslash `\` on Windows and found this issue.

```
 server {
     location ~ \.php$ {
-         root C:\Users\name\ProjectOfPHP; # 404
+         root C:/Users/name/ProjectOfPHP; # Use this pattern
     }
 }
```